# Android - using Jsoup with android_asset html file

Tags: android, jsoup

Ok well I have been using Jsoup to parse html from remote urls using:

```
Jsoup.connect(url).timeout(20000).get();
```

I am now trying to read local html files which I have stored in the `assets` folder. I have done a lot of searching but I cannot find a solution. On the [Jsoup example - Load a Document from a File](http://jsoup.org/cookbook/input/load-document-from-file), they say to do the following:

```
File input = new File("/tmp/input.html");
Document doc = Jsoup.parse(input, "UTF-8", "http://example.com/");
```

From what I've read, the path to my file would be - `file:///android_asset/results_2009.html`.

[image]

However I always get `no such file or directory`, so how do I get a local file into Jsoup?

Do I need to use `AssetManager` or something? Please can someone point me in the right direction.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`Jsoup.parse()` has an [overload which takes an InputStream](http://jsoup.org/apidocs/org/jsoup/Jsoup.html#parse%28java.io.InputStream,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%29).
You can use the `AssetManager` to obtain an `InputStream` to your file and use it:

```
InputStream is=null;

try {
    is=getAssets().open("results_2009.html");
    Document doc = Jsoup.parse(is, "UTF-8", "http://example.com/");
} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
} finally {
    if(is!=null)
        is.close();
}
```